# Template Return Issue in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

I need to know about the below issue:

```
return Template[Session.get('renderTemplate')];
```

here "Session.get('renderTemplate')" is gets template name.

When i am using this return statement is dynamic template loading using sessions but it returns `[object Object]` but not template data. I didn't know what mistake i did also.So can you please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you might not be following the instructions here:

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze#templatefoo-is-not-a-function-and-does-not-return-a-string

Could it be that you are using:

```
{{myHelper}}
```

instead of

```
{{> myHelper}}
```

as required as of meteor 0.8?